# Enable web request logging with Application Insights when using Play framework

Tags: azure, playframework, azure-application-insights

We have a Java web application that uses Play Framwork. How can I add web request logging using Application Insights? Documentation is available for other project types https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-get-started#4-add-an-http-filter

Comment: facing the same question...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using playframework 2.7, on the Java side, there are JavaHttpFilters. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/JavaHttpFilters

Unfortunately, these do not implement javax.servlet.Filter which is what the documentation you linked to uses. The documentation says you should register the filter [`WebRequestTrackingFilter`](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/blob/master/web/src/main/java/com/microsoft/applicationinsights/web/internal/WebRequestTrackingFilter.java). Basically it fills out a `RequestTelemetry` using an `HttpServerHandler` then sends it to ApplicationInsights using a [TelemetryClient](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/blob/241e467bb6dc72eac993720d97fc30804b1be26d/core/src/main/java/com/microsoft/applicationinsights/TelemetryClient.java).

In your `play.mvc.Filter`, you will do the same thing. Create a `TelemetryClient` (you probably want to use DI to inject this into your `Filter`). In your `Filter`'s `apply` method, create a [`RequestTelemetry`](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/blob/241e467bb6dc72eac993720d97fc30804b1be26d/core/src/main/java/com/microsoft/applicationinsights/telemetry/RequestTelemetry.java), then send it using [`TelemetryClient#trackRequest`](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/blob/241e467bb6dc72eac993720d97fc30804b1be26d/core/src/main/java/com/microsoft/applicationinsights/TelemetryClient.java#L332).